# Filter/recover Promise.all result

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Ex:

```
function myFunc(args ...){
  ...
  return Promise.all(myPromisesArray)
}
```

If a promise inside `myPromisesArray` fails, i will only get the rejection reason in the return value.

Is there a way to recover all the other resolved values?

Comment: Do you control the promises that you are executing?

Comment: The result? No it is arbitrary.

Comment: No I mean are you writing the code for the promises. If you are don't call the reject function and just return the result. Promises will fail and stop executing as soon as something fails

Comment: Ah no. I dont have that control.

Comment: Several solutions here: [ES6 Promise.all() error handle - Is .settle() needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605253/es6-promise-all-error-handle-is-settle-needed/36605453#36605453).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Promise.all have a callback that is fired when there are success AND failures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978838/does-javascript-promise-all-have-a-callback-that-is-fired-when-there-are-success)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Q, then there's a function called [`Q.allSettled`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled) that basically does what you ask for.

Otherwise, this simple function will give you the results of *all* promises, and tell you whether the succeeded or failed. You can then do whatever you need to do with the promises that succeeded or failed.

```js
/**
 * When every promise is resolved or rejected, resolve to an array of
 * objects
 *   { result: [ Promise result ], success: true / false }
**/
function allSettled(promises) {
  return Promise.all(
    promises.map(
      promise => promise.then(
        // resolved
        (result) => ({ result: result, success: true }),
        // rejected
        (result) => ({ result: result, success: false })
      )
    )
  );
}

// example usage:
const one = Promise.resolve(1);
const two = Promise.reject(2);
const three = Promise.resolve(3);

allSettled([ one, two, three ])
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results[0]); // { result: 1, success: true }
    console.log(results[1]); // { result: 2, success: false }
    console.log(results[2]); // { result: 3, success: true }
  });
```